# Problems with SEXTANTE

Tags: grass-gis, ubuntu, saga, sextante, qgis-2

maybe the answer is somewhere, but i can't find it right now... I'm getting problems with SEXTANTE and algorithms with GRASS, SAGA...

Always is the same, they can't open the files, the error is the folowing:

> Oooops! The following output layers could not be open Convex Hull:
>   ***/home/luismi/Escritorio/para_eliminar/interpolaciones.shp*** The above
>   files could not be opened, which probably indicates that they were not
>   correctly produced by the executed algorithm Checking the log
>   information might help you see why those layers were not created as
>   expected This algorithm requires SAGA to be run. A test to check if
>   SAGA is correctly installed and configured in your system has been
>   performed, with the following result: SAGA seems to be correctly
>   installed and configured

As you can see is not a problem with spaces between names, neither is a problem of writable directory because I tried to write in Desktop folder.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and Qgis is 2.0 version (was updated from repositories from 1.8 and I think i had the same problem...)

Please help... I need this correctly working to continue my project.

Thanks to everybody!!!

Comment: Perhaps the file /home/luismi/Escritorio/para_eliminar/interpolaciones.shp is there but not writable (generated by another user ID, read-only or whatever other reason)?

Comment: ummm... that file "interpolaciones.shp" is the algorithm output. It happend with all outputs. Besides I've changed the output folder to my /home directory, but Qgis still try to look in the /tmp/processing folder..

Comment: You will need a QGIS expert to solve this...

Comment: I think so... thank you very much :D I'll try to make a clean instalation in a virtual machine and see what happens. Maybe is a problem with my computer.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry Mark, I haven't find any solution yet... I'll try to make a clean installation on a virtual machine to determine if the problem is my computer or is the software. If you find out what happens earlier, please tell me :D I think this tool is very powerful... if it works :P